# Rendering data from Axios promise into HTML with mustache rendering [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, mustache

I am trying to get data from an API rendered to HTML. I am making the request to the API with:

```
const openWeatherMapApiUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";

async function getWeatherData() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(openWeatherMapApiUrl, {
            params: {
                q: "London,uk",
                appId: "956d289b64e4e226bdef9ce1f93b475b"
            }
        })
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

From there, I am rendering that data to my HTML with:

```
renderWeather = () => {
    var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
    var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {
        cityName: getWeatherData()
    });
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = rendered;
}
```

Instead of rendering the data, it renders `[object Promise]`. I understand that this may be due to the fact that the promise has yet to be fulfilled, so I've also tried fulfilling it by writing:

`getWeatherData().then((response) => {return response})` and different variations of it in different places, yet this still returns the same `[object Promise]` response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getWeatherData` returns a promise that needs to `await`-ed to get the data, and if reporting errors inside `getWeatherData` re-throw the error to inform the caller:

```
const openWeatherMapApiUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";

async function getWeatherData() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(openWeatherMapApiUrl, {
            params: {
                q: "London,uk",
                appId: "956d289b64e4e226bdef9ce1f93b475b"
            }
        })
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;   // reject returned promise
    }
}
```

If errors are to be reported after calling the function, it can be simplified to

```
function getWeatherData() {
    return axios.get(openWeatherMapApiUrl, {
            params: {
                q: "London,uk",
                appId: "956d289b64e4e226bdef9ce1f93b475b"
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Both versions need to be `await`-ed when calling or processed in a Promise chain like

```
getWeatherData()
.then( data => console.log(data))
.catch( err => console.error(err));
```

Supplying data as an argument to `renderWeather` helps calling it from asynchronous code:

```
renderWeather = (weatherData) => {
    var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
    var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {
        cityName: weatherData
    });
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = rendered;
}
```